# SQL - Select + MAx()

Tags: sql, join, db2, max

I want to combine a list of salesmen with date of last sale by that salesman from the sales file.
Note that Salesmen may not have yet made any sales!

```
SELECT
    SLSNO,
    SLSNAME
FROM
    SALESMEN

SELECT
    SLSNO,
    max(SALEDATE)
FROM
    SALESHEADER
WHERE
    SALESMANNO = SLSNO
GROUP BY   
    SLSNO
ORDER BY
    SLSNO
```

Using ibm db2. Would prefer standard ANSI SQL if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second case below the `Latest Sale` will be `NULL` if they haven't made a sale yet.

```
-- if you want all salesmen who have made a sale
SELECT
    SLSNO,
    SLSNAME,
    MAX(SALEDATE) AS [Latest Sale]
FROM
    SALESMEN AS s
JOIN
    SALESHEADER AS h
ON
    h.SLSNO = s.SLSNO
WHERE
    SALESMANNO = SLSNO
GROUP BY
    SLSNO,
    SLSNAME


-- if you want all salesmen even if they don't have a sale
SELECT
    SLSNO,
    SLSNAME,
    MAX(SALEDATE) AS [Latest Sale]
FROM
    SALESMEN AS s
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    SALESHEADER AS h
ON
    h.SLSNO = s.SLSNO
WHERE
    SALESMANNO = SLSNO
GROUP BY
    SLSNO,
    SLSNAME
```

Comment: tried variation of this. Maybe db/3 won't not let me use max() like this

Comment: of course if will let you use max() like this - did you include all columns from your `select` that you do not aggregate in the `group by` clause?

Comment: deathApril was right!  however slow as hell because it lacks appropriate index.